# Recortar imagem com PHP sem bibliotecas

Tags: php

Estou trazendo algumas imagens do BD Mysql do qual algumas são horizontais e outras verticais. Vi que tem algumas bibliotecas que fazem esse recorte, porém gostaria de saber se existe algum meio de recortar a imagem sem a existência de bibliotecas.

Comment: Algo como a função `imagecrop`? As bibliotecas utilizam funções nativas ou extensões específicas para isso, então basta analisar o código fonte das que você conhece e ver o que pode usar.

Comment: Eu estava lendo a resposta que levou 1 ano e 8 meses para ser idealizada quando você a apagou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um exemplo basico.

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng('example.png');
$size = min(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $size, 'height' => $size]);
if ($im2 !== FALSE) {
    imagepng($im2, 'example-cropped.png');
}
?>
```

Na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecrop.php) você encontra informação sobre.

Comment: Olá Rafael. Certo, mas sem querer abusar muito rs rs rs, como eu faria para chamar a imagem recortada? Seria a variável $im2? <img src='".$img2."'>